# Javascript using Python function with eel

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I'm in the process of making a chatbot program with Python and JavaScript. I use eel to make the UI for chatbot, but exposed function from python code can't be used in JavaScript Code.

**Python Code**

```
@eel.expose
def responsedMessage(message):
    word = tokenize(message)
    if not word == '@':
        reply = load_w2v(word)
    else:
        reply = ''
    response = make_sentence(reply)
    return response
```

**JavaScript**

```
async function btnFunc(){
    if(!inputText.value) return false;
    output(inputText.value,'me');
    const response = await eel.responsedMessage(inputText.value);
    output(response,'robot');
}
```

**Error**

```
chatbot_js.html:60 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: eel.responsedMessage is not a function
at btnFunc (chatbot_js.html:60)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (chatbot_js.html:16)
```

Why is this error happened?

Answer (score 1):

you should put the **eel.start('main.html')** at the end of your python script

```
@eel.expose
def responsedMessage(message):
    word = tokenize(message)
    if not word == '@':
        reply = load_w2v(word)
    else:
        reply = ''
    response = make_sentence(reply)
    return response

eel.start('main.html')
```